# How to plot two normal distribution curves together- the second one shorter and narrower than the first one using numpy and matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, normal-distribution

I'd like to plot two normal distribution curves as shown below.
The shorter normal distribution curve on the left is also narrower as compared to the taller normal distribution curve on the right.

[image]

I tried the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

value = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, size=1000)
sns.kdeplot(x = value, ax = ax, linestyle = "--", color = "red")

value2 = np.random.normal(loc= -2,scale=2, size=1000)
sns.kdeplot(x = value2, ax = ax, linestyle = "--", color = "blue")
plt.show()
```

When the standard deviations (scales) of both curves are same (2 each), the width and height of both curves are almost equal as shown below:

[image]

When I reduce the scale/standard deviation of blue curve to 0.5 and keep the scale of red curve as 2, the width of blue curve gets narrower, but it becomes much taller as compared to the red curve as shown below:

[image]

Is it possible to reduce both the heights and the widths of the normal distribution curves at the same time for visualisation purpose? How can it be achieved using numpy, matplotlib or seaborn libraries in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The [`.normal()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) output is deliberately giving
you a distribution with unit area.
That is, integrating from -∞ .. +∞ yields 1.0.
This proves very useful when modeling e.g.
[pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) probability density functions,
where we know that *something* occurred with probability 1.

In your code, you might replace

```
value = np.random.normal( ...
```

with

```
value = k * np.random.normal( ...
```

and then play around with `k` values
greater than 1, perhaps 2 or 3,
to see how the curve scales up.
Adjust it to taste.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

EDIT

Oh, I see, you're using [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html).
Don't do that.
It wants the area to integrate to 1.0.
When you scale by `k` it will
scale by `1 / k`.

Prefer [scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) instead.

Comment: I tried with different values of k both lower and higher than 1. However, I am not able to get the required plots.